# In which situation does this macro can cause an error?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider the following macro

```
#define SQ(x) ((x) * (x));
```

In which situation does using this macro  cause an error?

Comment: `SQ(i++)` causes undefined behavior

Comment: If `x` is a non numeric type?

Comment: The semicolon would cause problems when using something like: `printf("The square of %d is %d", 2, SQ(2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the case that its argument has side effects when evaluated. For example, SQ(i++) is undefined behaviour.